# Geth infinite sync issue (or pending state entries never ~0)

Tags: go-ethereum

I am running a geth node:

> geth --cache=1024 --fast

Disk Info:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               VMware
Product:              Virtual disk
Revision:             2.0
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        214,748,364,800 bytes [214 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
LB provisioning type: unreported, LBPME=-1, LBPRZ=0
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Wed Jul  4 17:34:27 2018 CEST
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.
```

Memory info :

```
8 cores
12 gb
```

Now coming to the output of geth:

> eth.syncing command

```
{
  currentBlock: 5904361,
  highestBlock: 5904527,
  knownStates: 10990364,
  pulledStates: 10963864,
  startingBlock: 5904213
}
```

> eth.getBlock("latest").number

0

> eth.getBlock("pending").number

1

Here is one of my output logs:

```
INFO [07-04|17:24:35] Imported new state entries 
count=635  elapsed=1.821ms   processed=9865187 pending=24195  retry=0
duplicate=882 unexpected=3966`
```

Please focus on pending value 24195. This value always keeps changing between 20k-40k but never comes to 0

To me it seems like ethereum is updating faster than my node is catching up. It is like Ethereum network is always one step ahead in the trie and my node is never able to catch up.

If anyone has faced this situation or has expert knowledge, suggest what to do in such a scenario?

Comment: Do you have a SSD or HDD? A magnetic disk HDD do not have enough perfomance to keep up to date (geth uses a lots of IO resources). If you are using VMWare on top of a SSD it might be that emulation cause additional perfomance drop. One option is to launch geth in light mode.

Comment: its a HDD, I am going to use AWS EBS SSD volume with parity and update. This issue seems to be very famous among new comers and no consolidated resolution has been put up yet

Answer (score 1):

My node is now fully synced in 6 hours. I used [parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity) to sync the node with --geth option. No SSD was needed, working well in RAID:

Command:

```
nohup parity --mode active --tracing off --pruning fast 
--db-compaction ssd --cache-size 3072 --geth &
```

**--mode**

Used: "active"

Explanation : Set the operating mode. MODE can be one of: last - Uses the
        last-used mode, active if none; active - Parity
        continuously syncs the chain; passive - Parity syncs
        initially, then sleeps and wakes regularly to resync; dark
        - Parity syncs only when the RPC is active; offline -
        Parity doesn't sync. (default: last)

**--tracing**

Used: off

Explanation: Indicates if full transaction tracing should be enabled.
        Works only if client had been fully synced with tracing
        enabled. BOOL may be one of auto, on, off. auto uses last
        used value of this option (off if it does not exist).
        (default: auto)

**--pruning**

Used: Fast

Explanation: Configure pruning of the state/storage trie. METHOD may be
        one of auto, archive, fast: archive - keep all state trie
        data. No pruning. fast - maintain journal overlay. Fast but
        50MB used. auto - use the method most recently synced or
        default to fast if none synced. (default: auto)

**--db-compaction**

used: ssd

Explanation: Database compaction type. TYPE may be one of: ssd -
        suitable for SSDs and fast HDDs; hdd - suitable for slow
        HDDs; auto - determine automatically. (default: auto)

Note: Server has HDD RAID disk which is quite close to SSD in writes but much much slower (100x slower) in reads. So I think I fooled parity in believing it is on SSD, don't try it on HDD (not sure what will happen )

**--cache-size**

Used: 3072

Explanation: Override database cache size. (default: 128)

Note: I have huge server so I can afford to use 3GB cache. Although cache size seems to boost sync exponentially , be careful with the number.

**--geth**

Explanation: Run in Geth-compatibility mode. Sets the IPC path to be the
        same as Geth's. Overrides the --ipc-path and --ipcpath
        options. Alters RPCs to reflect Geth bugs. Includes the
        personal_ RPC by default.

Note: geth mode is available on parity, later I used geth attach and ran eth functions.

**--warp**

Explanation: Does nothing; warp sync is enabled by default.

Note: [Warp](https://wiki.parity.io/Warp-Sync) is default for Parity , it is amazing feature which syncs Ethereum states fast.

References: https://wiki.parity.io/Configuring-Parity

Final note: I don't understand why people are still using Geth, Parity synced entire blockchain in 6-8 hours while Geth could never achieve it (Node was running for weeks). Maybe I was missing something, thoughts are welcome.